# Picking out the right characters of a String;

Tags: java

I'm trying to pick out the characters of a string that come just before and just after the part of the string that matches another string, creating a completely different string. I.e. when the method `wordEnds(String str, String word)` is called, and `str = "XY1XY"` and `word = "XY"`, then the new string would be `"11"`.

Here is what I have so far:

```
package codingBat;

 public class CodingBat {
  public static String wordEnds(String str, String 
   word) {
    String newStr = null;

      if(str.equals(word)) {
         return ""; 
      }
      else if(!str.contains(word)) {
          return "";
      }
      else {
          for(int i = 0;i < str.length();i++) {
              if((word.equals(str.substring(i,i+1)))){
               newStr = newStr + (str.substring(i-1,i+2));
              }
              else {
                 return newStr;
              }
          }
          return newStr;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why "11"?  The string `str` only has one "1" in it...

Comment: So the string word =  "XY" occurs twice in str, once before the 1, and again after. Since it occurs twice, and the method is meant to pull the character that is before and after the occurrence, it pulls the "1" that occurs after the first "XY" and another "1" that occurs just before the final "XY", creating the new string "11".

Comment: ok what should happen for XY1XYXY?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use regex, pattern for your example ll look like this `XY.*XY`. But You have to change the `XY`to the string parameter so it ll be `pattern = str+"(.*)"+str`. Then you can use the group and read the string from middle
Here is a code:

```
    static String middleString(String str, String word) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(str + "(.*)" + str);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
        matcher.matches();
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
```

This call:

```
System.out.println(middleString("XY", "XY11XY"));
```

Returns `11`